# double dispatch and Visitor Pattern

Tags: c++

While i was studying Composite Pattern I have encountered the concept of double dispatch and Visitor Pattern.
I have checked on wikipedia for double dispatch (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) and followed the example.
I have understood in C++ virtual functions are dispatched dynamically and the function overloading is done statically, but my problem is the solution. 
It states the problem can be resolved by simulation double dispatch using a Visitor Pattern. 
Now I have checked several examples here and the example on GoF book for Visitor Pattern, but it's still  not clear to me how to apply the solution. Surely I am missing the point of Visitor Pattern.

Please can someone be so kind to explain the solution by completing the wikipedia example ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may want to have a look at `Boost.Variant` and the `boost::static_visitor<>` class template. It supports double dispatch.

Comment: [Huston we have a Pattern!](http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/)

Comment: check out the [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7360/MultiMethods-in-C-Finding-a-complete-solution)